# where should i add flex-direction property. should i add to the bootstrap row or column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

- Here i have added my code samples before and after i have changed my code, but don't no what makes the difference and the images on my website came up after i have changed this piece of code.

---

```
======Before======
<div class="row p-0 m-0 h-100 card-container catalog ">

<!---Image----->
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center image-wrap">
        <img alt="{{ catalog.name }}" class="p-0 m-0 ghost-hidden" [src]="catalog.image"  *ngIf="catalog.image">
    </div>


<!-- name of Image-->   
    <div class="col-12 ghost-bg ghost-bg-dark catalog-wrap">
        <h3 class="p-0 m-0 ghost-bar ghost-white g-w-80">
            {{ catalog.name }}
        </h3>
        <h3 class="ghost-visible-element ghost-bar ghost-white g-w-50"></h3>
    </div>


<!--  Icon--->
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center more">
        <i class="icon-arrow-slice"></i>
    </div>
</div>





scss

.catalog {
        padding: 5px;
        height: 400px;

        .image-wrap {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;

            img {
                width: auto;
                max-width: 80%;
                max-height: 100%;

                &.pp-default-image {
                    width: 50%;
                }
            }
        }




======After==============
====== Here i have moved Image text the first div=======
====== secondly i have moved flex-direction from my image-wrap class to category class========
<div class="row p-0 m-0 h-100 catalog-card-container catalog">

<!--- Image Text--->
  <div class="col-12 ghost-bg ghost-bg-dark catalog-wrap">
    <h3 class="p-0 m-0 ghost-bar ghost-white g-w-80">
      {{ catalog.name }}
    </h3>
    <h3 class="ghost-visible-element ghost-bar ghost-white g-w-50"></h3>
  </div>


<!-- Image--->
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center image-wrap">
        <img alt="{{ catalog.name }}" class="p-0 m-0 ghost-hidden" [src]="catalog.image" [default]="setDefaultImg(catalog.uiMetadata.style)" *ngIf="catalog.image">
    </div>


<!--Icon--->

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center more">
        <i class="icon-arrow-slice"></i>
    </div>
</div>





scss


.category {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
        .image-wrap {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            // flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;

            img {
                width: auto;
                max-width: 80%;
                max-height: 100%;

                &.pp-default-image {
                    width: 50%;
                }
            }
        }
```

- i don't no what made the difference, after i have moved flex-direction images started showing up
- can anyone please explain me what made the difference
- i never asked questions on stack overflow along with code.. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Please, let me know for further information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create this in https://codesandbox.io ?